# Google analytics resulting in a large percentage of non programming related questions

Tags: discussion, tags

There have been issues with the  [google-analytics](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-analytics) tag for years, and now they have been compounded by

- [google-data-studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-data-studio)
- [data-studio-custom-visuals](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/data-studio-custom-visuals)
- [ga4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ga4)

[Google Data Studio](https://datastudio.google.com/navigation/reporting) is a web application as is [Google analytics](https://analytics.google.com/analytics/web/#/) and thereby [ga4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ga4) as well.

Questions under both of these tags seem to have a high chance of being about the web application and not being programming related.

There are a small number of [google-analytics](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-analytics) and [ga4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ga4) tagged questions that could in fact be classified as programming related as they are regarding the Snippet applied to your website.  I am inclined to think that everything related to the web applications themselves including figuring out filters in Google analytics cannot be classified as programming related.

I try to go though everything tagged [google-analytics](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-analytics) as much as I can and close-vote them as not programming related and point over to [Web apps](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/). However this doesn't seem to work very well; the questions never seem to get closed and people are still answering non programming related questions.

Should we change the [google-analytics](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-analytics) and [ga4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ga4) tags to something more like Google-analytics-snippet or Ga4-snippet, and do away with [google-data-studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-data-studio) completely?

I am of two minds regarding [data-studio-custom-visuals](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/data-studio-custom-visuals), there could be code with that.

I realize this won't stop people from posting but maybe not having a tag for them may help getting the questions closed faster?

Note: this confusion was caused partly by a section of the Google Analytics documentation which pointed to Stack Overflow even when it was non programming related.   I have talked to the team and that link was removed last year.

Example of non programming related Google analytics questions:

[Transform referral-traffic into organic with Organic Search Sources](https://stackoverflow.com/q/66771294/1841839)
[Average time on page for a specific sequence of pageviews](https://stackoverflow.com/q/66754055/1841839)

Comment: When is google analytics on topic? Integrating the tag? Configuring the options? When I did that I didn't feel like I was programming. However there's an API, which would make interacting with it on topic. Maybe a rename?

Comment: Google-analytics-api is the tag for API related questions.    I'm thinking issues with configuring the snippet could be web apps exchange.    I'm not sure it's really programming, but that will complicate the issue

Comment: Just had thought that if we want to do away with Google analytics snippet questions what will we do with Google tag manager questions?  Tag manager is also technically a web app.   I may have opened a larger can of worms than i thought originally.

Comment: We may want to replace `google-analytics` with `google-analytics-snippet` and then put a message on `google-analytics` which suggests that people ask on the Web App stackexchange

Comment: @ProQ that seems like a good place to start, I went ahead and edited the tag and added something to that effect in the title.

Comment: "..the questions never seem to get closed..." You could ask the SOCVR or just here. I used a SEDE query to get all [unclosed questions in this tag with close votes](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1389517/questions-in-the-google-analytics-tag-with-pending-close-votes-sorted-by-close-vo) and went over them.

Comment: Can i get the definition of SOCVR and SEDE when you have a chance?

Comment: You can also simply in the close vote review queue filter by tag, that should be more accurate (I had a lot of questions that had close votes long time ago but either they aged away or the question got reopened). SEDE is the data explorer (https://data.stackexchange.com/) and SOCVR is a community of users of SO that coordinate their close or delete voting activity (https://socvr.org/). I've only heard of them.

Comment: The easiest would be if you tell people to go to https://stackoverflow.com/review/close/ and apply the "google-analytics" tag filter. However there are more than 19k google-analytics questions. That are a lot really.

Comment: Like i said i have been trying but im one woman army :)

Comment: Another useful mechanism that works for every one-person army: downvote off-topic questions so that they get automatically deleted. The automatic deletion ([roomba](https://stackoverflow.com/help/roomba)) kicks in if the question score is <= 0 and there are no positive answers (see link for details). That means you could concentrate on all questions with score <= 1 and no answer with score > 1 and downvote them. That might be faster than closing them.

Comment: @Trilarion I think plenty of google-analytics questions are really about google-analytics-api or snippets, so you can't just mass close them all even if they're not properly tagged...

Comment: @eis You're right. That's why I looked over each question in the tag with close votes carefully and also only recommended to downvote the questions that are truly off-topic. One should be really careful not to close or trigger deletion of ontopic questions.

Comment: if its api related i normally retag them with the Google-analytics-api so if you can search on google-analytics without google-analytics-api that might help

Comment: @eis those need a retagging :D

Comment: Here we have a bad example of a Google-Analytics question relating to the snippet.  https://stackoverflow.com/q/66795969/1841839.  So can we call this coding or do we call this https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/?

Comment: @Trilarion if you ask nicely they (SOCVR) will also gladly spend reopen votes ;)

Comment: I decided to send this link to the Google Analytics Api team at Google.  It will give bring them in on this and give them the option to chime in and maybe change any links they have on their site after a decision is made.

Comment: While I understand @DalmTo' concern there's also another side of the issue. There's almost no chances to get Google Analytics-related question answered on stackexchange. The stackoverflow tag is watched by a large number of top-notch experts while stackexchange looks a little bit like a desert. So chopping off non programming question would give us a cleaner tag but overall community effect would hardly be positive.

Comment: @ДмитроБулах I am hoping to get google to point documentation at Web apps and web masters. Questions do get answered there and if knowledgeable users like yourself and Michele Pisani who know that people are on those sites looking for help for the non programming related issues.  They will still get answers just in the correct location.

Comment: I suppose it could help if we can somehow 'move' questions to SE instead of closing them on SO however I don't know if it's possible.

Comment: When i close the questions i try to always point them at the appropriate stack exchange site.  I have even gotten a few thank yous and seen them post over there.

Answer (score 9):

- I noticed that in the post you recommended removing [google-data-studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-data-studio) completely. A portion of [google-data-studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-data-studio) questions are for developer features like [Community Connectors](https://developers.google.com/datastudio/connector), [Community Viz](https://developers.google.com/datastudio/visualization), [embedding](https://developers.google.com/datastudio/share/embed), [API](https://developers.google.com/datastudio/api) etc  which are directly programming related. In fact, [the official recommendation](https://developers.google.com/datastudio/support#finding_support) is that developers ask questions on Stack Overflow using the [google-data-studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-data-studio) tag. Thus, My current stance is against removing the [google-data-studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-data-studio) tag.
- Regarding [data-studio-custom-visuals](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/data-studio-custom-visuals), there are 13 questions on this tag of which 5 are relevant. And all questions except one are also tagged with [google-data-studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-data-studio). My recommendation would be to merge this tag with [google-data-studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-data-studio).

Comment: I agree with this if a portion of Questions relating to [tag:google-data-studio]  then I agree the tag should remain.

Answer (score -15):

Obviously, mine is only one point of view on the matter. It is neither a question of opposing what DalmTo says nor of creating havoc. I'm just saying that if you are a good developer you don't need to ask on Stack Overflow, so it is normal that whoever asks is at a low level or 0 level, and it is these people who bring the forum to life.

For this reason, I disagree with limiting the range of inclusion of questions on related arguments or relevant topics.

It is true that many questions related to `Google Analytics` are not strictly related to programming but it is also true that there are others that are relevant and that are not only about the snippet.

Some questions (but also sometimes answers, where from the questions it is not clear that a code is needed) may be more evident such as the snippet but also **JavaScript** code to pass data to Analytics, others are less evident such as the use of `regex` in filters or `analytics` issues (not Google) that cover mathematical aspects. According to this criterion then also Google Tag Manager is a Web App and also regex-related questions (for example with regex tags) may not be related to programming because they could be used in Web App rather than in PHP code.

For example, this is a recent question on Google Analytics, voted to be closed because it is deemed not related to programming, the answer is that it is obtainable with a script in JavaScript: [Google Analytics: How can I see the IP addresses of those visiting my site?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66763851/google-analytics-how-can-i-see-the-ip-addresses-of-those-visiting-my-site)

There would be a multitude of posts that are out of order, even with programming language tags.

Furthermore, *Stack Overflow* is known by all as the place to find solutions, and the solutions are found and are very reliable. While *Stack Exchange* I believe most users don't even know what it is (never seen or noticed in Google search results).

I've been seeing a large number of Google Analytics tagged questions since yesterday that are closed regardless, without even thinking that they may be related to programming.

**Everything** (or rather, more than it seems at first glance) **is programming.** I certainly wouldn't accept a question about flowers, but the boundary between different programming levels depends on the points of view, the IDEs used (you can develop apps with just drag & drop and two or three lines of code ... this is programming too) and perception.

People need help and I don't think certain topics are that far from context. **This isn't the supportive spirit I've always found in Stack Overflow**.

I think it is better to consider Google Analytics and related apps like Google Tag Manager and so on as valid first, rather than spending time closing posts from people in need. These Google tools are used all over the world and are the future, in addition to doing indexing damage (however absorbable) to Stack Overflow... users cannot be prevented from posting.

Comment: Requested comment on downvote: No, everything is not programming. If it was, there wouldn't be dozens (hundreds?) of Stack Exchange sites for other topics. Sure, some of them are kind of unnecessary/overly specific (e.g. the OS specific SEs that could/should be tags under SuperUser). General is good; I'm willing to consider anything which involves writing code of any kind (e.g. Excel formulas), even drag'n'drop block programming as taught to first graders, as programming. But if the use of Google analytics alone doesn't meet that bar, it's not for StackOverflow, period. It's just clutter.

Comment: Meanwhile, thanks for the comment. Obviously the 'everything is programming' is extreme to indicate that there is not only programming of a certain level. In the link in main post it also talks about the use of regex (with a regex to use), while in the one I put in my post above there is a script to an API to recover the IP address. Both posts were considered non-programming related. I just wonder if the same questions hadn't included the word 'Google Analytics' if they would have been considered to be closed.

Comment: I am sorry feel this way, however I expected it that's why I sent you this link.  A large number of the questions you have answered [user:5640200 google-analytics](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user:5640200+[google-analytics]) over the years have been in the Google analytics tag,   I have noticed you answering questions after I have closed voted them and pointed the author to web apps, rather then adding a close vote to the question.  I felt there was a chance you would also have any opinion on any approach to addressing this issue. I felt you deserved the option to join the debate.

Comment: That being said: I disagree to JavaScript snippint being programming related, **Programming is a way to “instruct the computer to perform various tasks”.** The JavaScript snippet is configuration / or setup of the Google Analytics Web application.   Creating filters on the Google Analytics Web application is also not programming related, its again configuration of a web application.   (That is why i downvoted)

Comment: I'm sorry if you thought that my reply after your closure request you took it as disrespect. It was absolutely not that. Rather, sometimes the closing requests were not such, other times they were plausible. Anyway I thought that if a question were to actually be closed it would reach 3 votes. Sometimes it happened, sometimes it didn't. I've always thought about helping with clear requests. So now the common goal is to get rid of all GA questions (not Google API) from stackoverflow? And who talks about regex we ask the context, and if it is Analytics it closes while for a script it's fine?

Comment: Just for alignment, I will remove this post shortly, whoever wanted to express has done so, I myself have expressed my opinion. Isn't it nice to see that the effort and time I've put in over the last few years to value a portion of stackoverflow comes down to this post with a series of negative votes and terminology quibbles. I think this is understandable even to the best developers in the World.

Comment: Please don't remove this post, we need all the opinions we can get on this in order to come to a consensus and a valid decision that we can all live with.   You have an opinion we all respect that.  Opinions should never be deleted.  I am more then willing to compromise on the Javascript snippet part if the consensus agrees to it, but we cant have a consensus if you delete your opinion. From public record.  From the bottom of my heart i ask you to let it remain.

Comment: Linda, I can also keep this post (in addition to the regret that the ban for negative votes was not included), I honestly believe that the solution depends on what you think you do. Anyone who writes about Analytics like me, ДмитроБулах and a few others see it in one way, those who are strong developers see it in another. Not to repeat myself, but "evreryting is programming" and "instruct the computer to perform various tasks" have a very close boundary. I talked about drag & drop and someone said it would be accepted, like Excel Formulas [continue...]

Comment: [from above] Then also the configuration of a trigger in Google Tag Manager is web app and is not different from a filter in Analytics, however this also instructs the computer on server i.e. if (hostname! = 'mydomain) {} // no operations... CSS is not programming, and like these many other stackoverflow questions and topics. Google Analytics is not just snippets, however it is better for me to leave everything like this, nobody complains, users are happy, we are managing them well and we avoid fighting frustrating battles by closing answer and sending users to a platform that no one knows.

Comment: After the last modification that was made to the text considering it noise, when it had a great emotional importance ... given the context, I will remove the message by concentrating my point of view in a comment to the main post. The concept was however expressed and shared. Thanks

Comment: @MichelePisani - you are free to simply roll back if you disagree. I removed the chatty part as it is irrelevant to your point, but not adamant about that. However, the note about downvotes is pure noise and only attracts further votes, I strongly advise you to remove it either way. Do keep the answer, though - downvotes here do not mean much except for disagreement with your PoV. You neither lose rep not standing with the community.

Comment: Negative votes certainly mean disappointment, but the fact that that part can attract other negative votes without a real comparison shows that there's no interest in comparison but only closure of thought. It's a post for a debate not to shoot judgments on a right or wrong answer. There isn't real right or wrong answer. I develop too and I understand both the one and the other side. This is the reason for my disappointment. In any case, the discussion has already been defined at the time, for me there was a lack of interpretation or perhaps I was not good at conveying the desired message.