# How can I improve the clarity of this question?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, closed-questions, reopen-closed

I had [a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73584117/data-studio-inconsistent-in-summing-metrics) about metric handling in [Data Studio](https://datastudio.google.com/overview) which was initially closed for "details or clarity". I edited it extensively according to the guidance of a highly-ranked user, and it was reopened for a couple of days. 9 hours ago, it was closed again for the same reason, without any answers.

I'd like to be clearer about it if possible; I'm just not sure where I can still improve it. I've had many much less detailed questions on other Stack accounts that never had any problems, so I'm at a bit of a loss.

Comment: Not an expert, but on first glance the question doesn't seem to be about programming or software engineering?

Comment: @BDL Has to do with metric processing by a Google service, which I believe falls under the purview of database manipulation, or at least spreadsheets. I just followed where other Data Studio questions were being left, i.e. the Google Cloud collective. If there's a better place to leave it I can certainly move it.

Comment: When I briefly look over the [tag:google-data-studio] tag, I see a bunch of questions that have actual code in them - looks like SQL, or some variant. Does your problem actually involve writing code, or are you just clicking around in a GUI? Stack Overflow is not tech support; if you are having problems with someone else's software, that's a question for the authors of the software. If the point is to end up with created code at the end, and the *code looks right to you but does the wrong thing*, then you can ask about the code; but we don't really care *how* you got the code normally.

Comment: That said, the Google Cloud collective may have its own policies and customs.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel That's true. This feels like a fringe case, since I suspect I'm misunderstanding how the database join function is meant to work with this, but there's also a chance that it's just the software being weird, and I'm not sure which it is. I suppose I could reframe the question to reflect that more clearly, thank you.

Comment: My mini-2cts: Your Qt (Question) starts directly with "*blends GA4 and UA data*", => maybe introduce the whole Scenario in a bit more "generic" sense, + all the Data you then provide requires "a lot of scrolling" before coming to the "Issue" Section where you are actually asking your Qt... => Maybe move/mention the "real" Question already much more at the Top of the Body of the Qt, for possible Answerers to read the "few Screens of Scrolling with Data" with already the Question in their Head... :idea: // I "liked" your Qt btw, the more Info, always the better for me, I don't mind scrolling...

Comment: Details=✅ Clarity=❌ (see ↑chivracq↑). As BDL notes: "_on first glance the question doesn't seem to be about [programming or software engineering](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/420218))_". That's the issue. It's about data blending & joins (on topic) but it's not obvious & not in the title; also why it was one of the close reasons by an active Google Analytics user. I (active on Google Data Studio) had also relayed the concerns initially (as it seemed like a question on the mismatch between GA4 vs UA metrics / sampling issue) and it took numerous comments & edits to understand the question.

Comment: As one of the close votes in question.  imo has [tag:google-data-studio] always been a web app and there for most questions are not programming related.  Its not a fringe case  I have a meta question about this already [Google analytics resulting in a large percentage of non programming related questions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/406188/1841839).   I would be surprised if i didn't close vote it as such, but doesn't show what each close voter voted just a consensus.  You should consider asking on  [Web apps stack exchange](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: Re *"I've had many much less detailed questions on other Stack accounts that never had any problems"*: That is one of many paradoxes of Stack Exchange. The [inverted pyramid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverted_pyramid_(journalism)) may or may not help.

Comment: @DaImTo Just because it's a webapp and uses GUI doesn't automatically make it off topic. If it's a question about database joining and the expected join doesn't seem to be happening in the language or the GUI he's coding in, I'd say that's on-topic, even if it isn't done in a white on black ui.

Comment: I’m not a subject matter expert at all, but even if this was directly in my field or interest, there’s no way I’d read even half of your question, it’s way too long.

Comment: The question was originally much shorter but the template I was provided instructed me to include all the information now currently included in the question. No pleasing everyone, I guess. Thanks for these additional insights, I might try again with a (hopefully more straightforward) setup.

Comment: @Boxbot i understand your frustration, but I still dont see this as a programing issue.  If anything its possibly a bug in data studio or in general mixing ua and ga4 analytics which was never going to end well.   That being said i can forward your question on to the team someone may decide to have a look but tbh its a big long even i didn't read the whole thing.   As always with google I cant say if anyone will respond.

Comment: Impressive question though. At this point it would be a shame to close it with that amount of time invested. Yes its long and I can't imagine that many people will take the time to read it; I can't really imagine that it'll receive an answer either. But is that a reason to make negative assumptions and close it? Not in my opinion. As such I'm voting to reopen, but I am refraining from upvoting as it is well out of my universe. In  fact that question kind of frightens me. Too many tables and numbers, help! I need an adult code base, I need an adult code base!

Comment: @Boxbot a bit of an update, contact one said to send it to contact two.  Again no promises you get a responses from the data studio team.

Comment: @DalmTo Thanks very much for the forward either way, it's more of a response than I honestly expected. Cheers!

Comment: But now do not ignore the comments you have been getting on the question or else that is kind of undoing all the good faith that has been assumed here :/

Comment: @Gimby Definitely on it, just got tied up with work. Hoping to respond today.